# WebMvcTest not giving any code coverage in IntelliJ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have integration test class for a controller as below

```
@WebMvcTest(DepartmentController.class)
public class DepartmentControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private DepartmentService departmentService;

    @MockBean
    private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Test
    void Get_Department_Returns_200_Ok_When_Department_Present() throws Exception {
        Optional<Department> deptOptional = Optional.of(new Department(1, "Tech"));
        when(departmentService.getDepartment(1)).thenReturn(deptOptional);
        assertThat(departmentService.getDepartment(1)).isEqualTo(deptOptional);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/department/{id}", 1)
        .contentType("application/json")
        ).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    //other tests
}
```

All the tests pass but it is not including the controller in the coverage results in IntelliJ

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**How I got this problem**
I have encountered the same problem with code coverage in Intellij when using @WebMvcTest. 
 When I ran a single class (i.e., **Run 'DepartmentControllerTest' with Coverage**), there was *No coverage result*.

**Possible Solution**
I have fixed it by running coverage on a directory level.
**Run 'Tests in 'controller' with Coverage** 
Image example of this action: [image]